# How to position tikz picture left, right, up, down as wish?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} % also loads tikz
\usepackage{labels}

\setmainfont{Holden}
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}

\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning, % for left=of, above=of etc.
  calc % for let syntax used in second example
}
\LabelCols=3%         Number of columns of labels per page
\LabelRows=7%         Number of rows of labels per page
\LeftBorder=8mm%      Space added to left border of each label
\RightBorder=8mm%     Space added to right border of each label
\TopBorder=9mm%       Space to leave at top of sheet
\BottomBorder=2mm%    Space to leave at bottom of sheet
\numberoflabels=22
\begin{document}
% \begin{labels}
% \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={inner sep=0},
  node distance=5mm
]
   \node [Black] (text) {Vaijan\XeTeXglyph83s Honey};



  \path
    let
    \p1=(text.south west),
    \p2=(text.north east),
    \n1={\x2-\x1}, % width of text node
    \n2={\y2-\y1}  % height of text node
    in
% in all of the below some fraction of \n1 or \n2 is used to define the width of the ornaments
% set width of these ornaments to half the text node's width
   node [anchor=north] (below) at (text.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.5*\n1,symmetry=c]{69}}
   node [anchor=south] (above) at (text.north) {\pgfornament[width=0.5*\n1]{69}}



% use \n2 for ornament width here
   node [rotate=-90, left=of text, anchor=north] (left)  {\pgfornament[width=\n2]{46}}
   node [rotate=90, right=of text, anchor=north] (right) {\pgfornament[width=\n2]{46}}
% and \n1 here
   node [above=of above] (top)    {\pgfornament[width=\n1]{71}}
   node [below=of below] (bottom) {\pgfornament[width=\n1,symmetry=h]{71}}
%   node [anchor=north] (top) at (text.north)   {\pgfornament[width=\n1]{71}}
%   node [anchor=south] (bottom) at (text.south) {\pgfornament[width=\n1,symmetry=h]{71}}
% and 25% of width for the corner ornaments
   node [anchor=north west] at (top.north -| left.south)  {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1]{63}}
   node [anchor=north east] at (top.north -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=v]{63}}
   node [anchor=south west] at (bottom.south -| left.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=h]{63}}
   node [anchor=south east] at (bottom.south -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=c]{63}}; % <- note the \path doesn't end until here

   % draw frame
  \draw [Blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  \vspace{2cm};
  \node [anchor=south] (bellowaddress1) at (below.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.10*\textwidth]{88}};
  \setmainfont{Linux Biolinum O}
  \tiny
  \node [Brown, below, align=center] (bellowaddress3) at (bellowaddress1.south) {Md.Al-Helal, CSE, DU\\ 01515611989};
  \node [anchor=south, below] (bellowaddress2) at (bellowaddress3.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.10*\textwidth]{88}};
\end{tikzpicture}
% \end{center}
% \end{labels}
\end{document}
```

If I can position the text little upper than the upper gap will be minimized. How can I do this?

Comment: `\vspace*{-10pt}` before the tikzpicture?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer if I use `\vspace*{-10pt}` before tikzpicture environment then upper side flower content gone out of the page.

Comment: Are you sure to use `node distance=5mm` for every node ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I remove   `node distance=5mm` and add `node [above=0mm of above] (top)    {\pgfornament[width=\n1]{71}}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} % also loads tikz
\usepackage{labels}

\setmainfont{Holden}
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}

\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning, % for left=of, above=of etc.
  calc % for let syntax used in second example
}
\LabelCols=3%         Number of columns of labels per page
\LabelRows=7%         Number of rows of labels per page
\LeftBorder=8mm%      Space added to left border of each label
\RightBorder=8mm%     Space added to right border of each label
\TopBorder=9mm%       Space to leave at top of sheet
\BottomBorder=2mm%    Space to leave at bottom of sheet
\numberoflabels=22
\begin{document}
% \begin{labels}
% \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={inner sep=0},
  node distance=5mm
]
   \node [Black] (text) {Vaijan's Honey};



  \path
    let
    \p1=(text.south west),
    \p2=(text.north east),
    \n1={\x2-\x1}, % width of text node
    \n2={\y2-\y1}  % height of text node
    in
% in all of the below some fraction of \n1 or \n2 is used to define the width of the ornaments
% set width of these ornaments to half the text node's width
   node [anchor=north] (below) at (text.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.5*\n1,symmetry=c]{69}}
   node [anchor=south] (above) at (text.north) {\pgfornament[width=0.5*\n1]{69}}

% use \n2 for ornament width here
   node [rotate=-90, left=of text, anchor=north] (left)  {\pgfornament[width=\n2]{46}}
   node [rotate=90, right=of text, anchor=north] (right) {\pgfornament[width=\n2]{46}}
% and \n1 here
   node [above=0mm of above] (top)    {\pgfornament[width=\n1]{71}}
   node [below=of below] (bottom) {\pgfornament[width=\n1,symmetry=h]{71}}
%   node [anchor=north] (top) at (text.north)   {\pgfornament[width=\n1]{71}}
%   node [anchor=south] (bottom) at (text.south) {\pgfornament[width=\n1,symmetry=h]{71}}
% and 25% of width for the corner ornaments
   node [anchor=north west] at (top.north -| left.south)  {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1]{63}}
   node [anchor=north east] at (top.north -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=v]{63}}
   node [anchor=south west] at (bottom.south -| left.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=h]{63}}
   node [anchor=south east] at (bottom.south -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=c]{63}}; % <- note the \path doesn't end until here

   % draw frame
  \draw [Blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  \vspace{2cm};
  \node [anchor=south] (bellowaddress1) at (below.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.10*\textwidth]{88}};
  \setmainfont{Linux Biolinum O}
  \tiny
  \node [Brown, below, align=center] (bellowaddress3) at (bellowaddress1.south) {Md.Al-Helal, CSE, DU\\ 01515611989};
  \node [anchor=south, below] (bellowaddress2) at (bellowaddress3.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.10*\textwidth]{88}};
\end{tikzpicture}
% \end{center}
% \end{labels}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As you are using the Ti*k*Z `positioning` library with `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`, you can do:

```latex
\path ... node [above=1.5mm of above] (top) {...}
```

If you don't specify the `1.5mm`, then the `node distance` is used, which is `5mm` in your example (thus much larger).

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} % also loads tikz
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\usepackage{labels}

\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}

\LabelCols=3%         Number of columns of labels per page
\LabelRows=7%         Number of rows of labels per page
\LeftBorder=8mm%      Space added to left border of each label
\RightBorder=8mm%     Space added to right border of each label
\TopBorder=9mm%       Space to leave at top of sheet
\BottomBorder=2mm%    Space to leave at bottom of sheet
\numberoflabels=22

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={inner sep=0},
  node distance=5mm,
]
  \node [black] (text) {Vaijan\XeTeXglyph83s Honey};
  \path
    let
    \p1=(text.south west),
    \p2=(text.north east),
    \n1={\x2-\x1}, % width of text node
    \n2={\y2-\y1}  % height of text node
    in
   % In all of the below, some fraction of \n1 or \n2 is used to define the
   % width of the ornaments set width of these ornaments to half the text
   % node's width.
   node [anchor=north] (below) at (text.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.5*\n1,symmetry=c]{69}}
   node [anchor=south] (above) at (text.north) {\pgfornament[width=0.5*\n1]{69}}

   % Use \n2 for ornament width here.
   node [rotate=-90, left=of text, anchor=north] (left)  {\pgfornament[width=\n2]{46}}
   node [rotate=90, right=of text, anchor=north] (right) {\pgfornament[width=\n2]{46}}
   % And \n1 here
   node [above=1.5mm of above] (top)    {\pgfornament[width=\n1]{71}}
   node [below=of below] (bottom) {\pgfornament[width=\n1,symmetry=h]{71}}
   node [anchor=north west] at (top.north -| left.south)
     {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1]{63}}
   node [anchor=north east] at (top.north -| right.south)
     {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=v]{63}}
   node [anchor=south west] at (bottom.south -| left.south)
     {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=h]{63}}
   node [anchor=south east] at (bottom.south -| right.south)
     {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=c]{63}}; % <- note the \path
                                                    %    doesn't end until here

  % Draw frame
  \draw [blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
               (current bounding box.north east);
  \node [anchor=south] (bellowaddress1) at (below.south)
    {\pgfornament[width=0.10*\textwidth]{88}};
  \node [font=\tiny, Brown, below, align=center]
    (bellowaddress3) at (bellowaddress1.south)
    {Md.Al-Helal, CSE, DU\\ 01515611989};
  \node [anchor=south, below] (bellowaddress2) at (bellowaddress3.south)
    {\pgfornament[width=0.10*\textwidth]{88}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot without the precise fonts specified in your document (I don't have them, but this doesn't affect the answer):

[image]

P.S.:

- don't use `\vspace` inside the `tikzpicture` between Ti*k*Z statements;
- use option `font=\tiny` to change font size for Ti*k*Z nodes, as opposed to `\tiny` between Ti*k*Z statements.

If I replace the `\XeTeXglyph83` with a `'`, the label gets a proper apostrophe with the default fonts:

[image: proper apostrophe]

Comment: How to set position litter upper of text "Vaijan's Honey"?

Comment: Where the code reads `node [above=1.5mm of above] (top)`, reduce the value `1.5mm`. If you use `0mm`, the ornaments above the text and those at the top of the drawing will touch each other.

Comment: @alhelal Sorry for explaining things to you. Next time, I'll know that you don't want to understand nor to fix plain mistakes in your code (e.g., using `\vspace{2cm};` and `\tiny` inside the `tikzpicture` between Ti*k*Z statements is **completely broken**).